# C# Grid-like interface (similar to a file explorer) to delete files from a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently looking for a grid-like interface, that you can insert into a C# form. From the grid interface you are able to delete files, although not execute them.

I'm fairly new to C# and have not seen such as `Control` which can do this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ? https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005012/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090110-1.aspx . You can add path as a parameter on Delete buttton.

Also check this http://www.pr0g33k.com/blog/managing-files-with-aspnet/60

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control.